# Append to dataframe from another with calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv file that I read in and create 2 dataframes out of them.

I am taking the second dataframe and doing some calculations with it to append to the first dataframe. However it does not appear that what I am appending to the first data frame is actually happening.

What would I need to do to make this correct?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

m = pd.read_csv('DailyHistoricData.csv', header = None, index_col=0)
f = pd.read_csv('ImportFMP.csv', header = None)

for index in range(len(f)):
    a0 = f.ix[index, 0]
    a1 = f.ix[index, 1]
    a2 = f.ix[index, 7]
    a3 = f.ix[index, 8]-f.ix[index, 9]
    a4 = 100*f.ix[index, 2]
    a5 = f.ix[index, 10]-f.ix[index, 11]
    a6 = f.ix[index, 3]
    a7 = f.ix[index, 4]
    a8 = f.ix[index, 5]
    a9 = f.ix[index, 6]
    m.append([a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9])



print m.tail(3)
```

The info for f is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 720 entries, 0 to 719
Data columns (total 12 columns):
0     720 non-null int64
1     720 non-null int64
2     720 non-null float64
3     720 non-null int64
4     720 non-null int64
5     720 non-null int64
6     720 non-null int64
7     720 non-null int64
8     720 non-null int64
9     720 non-null int64
10    720 non-null float64
11    720 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(10)None
```

The first 5 rows of data is:

```
       0         1     2     3     4     5     6      7     8     9    10   11
0  11541  20110118  1.55  1296  1290  1295  1334  11838  1646  1393  525  687
1  11542  20110119  2.46  1295  1279  1282  1337  11825   697  2358  115  958
2  11543  20110120  0.70  1283  1271  1280  1312  11822  1141  1892  547  632
3  11544  20110121  0.83  1291  1282  1283  1310  11871  1597  1438  717  535
4  11545  20110124  1.23  1292  1282  1291  1304  11980  2143   904  628  325
```

The m info is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11544 entries, 1 to 11544
Data columns (total 19 columns):
1     11544 non-null int64
2     11544 non-null float64
3     11544 non-null int64
4     11544 non-null float64
5     11544 non-null float64
6     11544 non-null float64
7     11544 non-null float64
8     11544 non-null float64
9     11544 non-null int64
10    11544 non-null float64
11    11544 non-null float64
12    11544 non-null float64
13    11544 non-null int64
14    11544 non-null float64
15    11544 non-null float64
16    11544 non-null float64
17    11544 non-null int64
18    11544 non-null float64
19    11544 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(13), int64(6)None
```

And the first 5 rows of data for m is:

```
          1       2    3   4     5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  \
0                                                                            
1  19650302  507.99   70  56  1.77   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
2  19650303  507.35   46  73  1.07   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3  19650304  505.94 -104  96 -0.39   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
4  19650305  504.76 -200  66  0.14   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
5  19650308  504.86  160  89  0.90   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

    16  17  18  19  
0                  
1   0   0   0   1  
2   0   0   0   2  
3   0   0   0   3  
4   0   0   0   4  
5   0   0   0   5
```

Comment: Could you use concat instead? `m=m.concat([a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9],ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I get an error trying to use this...AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: [`append`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html?highlight=append#concatenating-using-append) does *not* operate in place.

Comment: Also, you should be vectorizing this by operating on the columns of interest all at once. Your current algorithm will be slow for even small frames with ~10k-100k elements.

Comment: Philip, could you give me some suggestions as to what you would recommend?

Comment: All you are doing is assigning and in some cases subtracting and multiplying the values in another dataframe, you could just do this on the whole dataframe or columns/series in a single pass rather than iteratively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should vectorize this:

```
In [68]: a3 = f.iloc[:, 8] - f.iloc[:, 9]

In [69]: a4 = 100 * f.iloc[:, 2]

In [70]: a5 = f.iloc[:, 10] - f.iloc[:, 11]

In [71]: toappend = pd.concat([a3, a4, a5], axis=1).rename(columns=dict(zip(range(3), list('abc'))))

In [72]: toappend.tail()
Out[72]:
        a    b    c
715 -1147  100 -247
716 -1022   89 -200
717  1491  109  328
718   712   87  194
719  -335   97  -84

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [73]: res = m.append(f.iloc[:, [0, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7]].join(toappend))

In [74]: res.tail()[['a', 'b', 'c']]
Out[74]:
        a    b    c
715 -1147  100 -247
716 -1022   89 -200
717  1491  109  328
718   712   87  194
719  -335   97  -84

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

In general, if you find yourself writing loops whose body contain element-wise arithmetic operations, you'll most likely be able to operate on the entire vector/`Series` object and take advantage of `numpy`'s speed in this respect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get this error when trying the above: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')

Comment: The first is the f:    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 720 entries, 0 to 719
Data columns (total 12 columns):
0     720 non-null int64
1     720 non-null int64
2     720 non-null float64
3     720 non-null int64
4     720 non-null int64
5     720 non-null int64
6     720 non-null int64
7     720 non-null int64
8     720 non-null int64
9     720 non-null int64
10    720 non-null float64
11    720 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(10)None

Comment: and the m:    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11544 entries, 1 to 11544
Data columns (total 19 columns):
1     11544 non-null int64
2     11544 non-null float64
3     11544 non-null int64
4     11544 non-null float64
5     11544 non-null float64
6     11544 non-null float64
7     11544 non-null float64
8     11544 non-null float64
9     11544 non-null int64
10    11544 non-null float64
11    11544 non-null float64
12    11544 non-null float64
13    11544 non-null int64
14    11544 non-null float64
15    11544 non-null float64
16    11544 non-null float64

Comment: 18    11544 non-null float64
19    11544 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(13), int64(6)None

Comment: That error message means you need to rename one or more of columns in `three_cols`, since one more of them has a name that is in `[0, 1, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: I renamed them to aa, ab and ac but still get the same error. I assume this is not what you meant by what that error means?

Comment: In your question can you show `f.info()` and `m.info()` and also show the first few rows of each frame?

Comment: Even better, would you care to post those 2 csv files in a dropbox folder and i'll take a look

Comment: Cant post it in public the data is sensitive. Give me your email and I can share it directly.

Comment: Thanks. The change to 0, 1, 6, 7 m.append though is different so does that still include the previous cols from f as I was trying to do?

Comment: @tbonejo right. now it keeps the old columns. i named the ones with the new calculations `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

Comment: actually the calculations become the same as some of the old columns, not new ones

Comment: Ok, so assign the new columns to the old columns (you'll probably have to remove the `a`, `b`, `c` names that I've given them).